# How do I search for every file with executable permission (+x) in my system?

Tags: permissions, osx, chmod

I need to find every single file that has executable permissions in my system, i think they end with `x@`.

I tried to `ls` every file and then grepping the output to match files with `x@`.

Like this:

```
ls -l | grep x@
```

But that just lists for the current directory and:

```
ls -ld | grep x@
```

Did not show all files. I need to search in all subdirectories. And I'm using FreeBSD tools (OS X).

Comment: Executable permissions and executable files aren't the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
find / -type f -perm /111 -print
```

or:

```
find / -type f -executable -print
```

Comment: `+111` is deprecated, offered to use `/111`. In the case better use `find / -type f -executable -print 2>/dev/null`

Comment: yep we can use -excutable flag

Comment: A side note: `-executable` doesn't work on Mac OS X.